# Disabling Schubert's PDF Browser plugin on Safari

Tags: safari, pdf

I use Safari and Firefox. To be able to view PDFs on Firefox on the fly, I use the [Schubert's PDF viewer](http://www.schubert-it.com/pluginpdf/). But, I would like to block it from loading my PDFs on Safari. I like Safari's way of handling PDFs a bit more. How can I disable a particular plugin on Safari?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I found a workaround. Move Schubert's plugin file which is located in:

```
/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/PDF Browser Plugin.plugin
```

or

```
/Users/YOUR_NAME/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/PDF Browser Plugin.plugin
```

to

```
/Users/YOUR_NAME/Library/Application Support/Firefox/Profiles/YOUR_PROFILE_DIRECTORY/plugins/
```

If you don't have `plugins` directory - create it. That's all :)

For Opera users - they should move plugin file to:

```
Library/Internet Plug-Ins/Disabled Plug-Ins/
```

Firefox and Safari don't use plugins from this location, but Opera does :)

Answer (score 1):

For that plugin (which is not a Safari Extension which is handled differently), you have to uninstall the plugin manaully by deleting the file, whcih means you don't get the plugin in Firefox

the support site says.

> **How do I uninstall PDF Browser Plugin?**
>   In Finder go to /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/ or /Library/Internet >Plug-Ins/ and move PDF Browser Plugin to the trash. Then restart your web browser.

Edit:
Looking at how the plugin is done, it is installed in Internet plug-ins which means it is Global.  I have looked to see if Firefox will load it from another location but have been unable to get FF to do that.

I've looked at extensions for both Firefox and Safari (such as ClickToPlugin) however you cannot disable a plugin in Safari as you can FF.

So my answer is that it cannot be done with Safari and global plugins.

Comment: That's the thing. I would like to keep it on for Firefox, but not have it interfere with Safari.

Comment: I think the solution is to place the plugin in a location that only Firefox looks for and not Safari, i'll look into it further